# Download some bytes and leave others

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, file, http

I've been loading a JavaScript file via AJAX for my new website but as the file gets bigger (more functions) Its getting increasingly inefficient to load it all when only a few functions are really used. If I divide the file into parts, I'll still end up downloading 100 functions and using less than 30. If I know where which function starts and ends (e.g. 3000 bytes and 3300 bytes) can I load these bytes only? Note: I am adding the HTML tag because I believe webmasters will have more experience with things like this

Comment: Why do you believe that would be more efficient?

Comment: @stark If `index.html` uses 3 functions (weighing 300bytes) it has to load a whole 3MiB file right now. so I was hoping I could just load those 300 bytes

Comment: use the network tab on dev tools to see how much longer a file with 1000 functions takes, versus a file with 30 functions. my hunch is that there will be little diff. that said, you might want to breakup the files into block of related functionality so that you can maintain
 them easier and load only the stuff you will use.

Comment: Just as a suggestion: Let a php script decide, which js-functions are needed, e.g. for modules in use or not in use, and call `selectedfunctions.js.php`

Comment: I think, you can write HTTP-handler on server-side to implement this. But, maybe, you will prefer to pass necessary function names instead of byte positions.

Comment: @ddlab that's what I was thinking, but I was looking for a js solution, If possible

Comment: @Shad I'm just saying that I **can** use byte positions if necessary.

Comment: @dandavis yeah you're right, but my script file weighs 3MB. And there are still 256 kbps internet users somewhere in the world :)

Comment: you can use a Range http header to fetch a partial response from a URL, but making a bunch of calls will probably take a lot of time. i would cut down the code you're using: 3mb is simply too much.

Answer (score 0):

count modules in html and let php deliver the code

```
<div class="module" name="module1">
...
</div>

<div class="module" name="module2">
...
</div>

<div class="module" name="module3">
...
</div>

<div class="module" name="module4">
...
</div>

<script>
    var foundmods = $('.module');
    var names = '';
    foundmods.each(function(){
        var mod = $(this);
        names += '|'+mod.attr('name');
    });
    names = substr(names,1);

    $.getScript('js/needed_functions.js.php?modules='+names)
    .done(function( script, textStatus ) {
        ...
    });
</script>
```

which is a very simplified suggestion.

Comment: Like I said, I **can't** use client side code. my question was regarding loading a fragment of a file via AJAX

Comment: @dandavis: I agree with you.

Comment: @user3088260: $.getScript() is an ajax shorthand, and this is a js-solution. If you ask for a serverside solution, it would look different. But both solutions save bandwidth for your 256kbps-users

Comment: @dandavis It was a typo! I meant I can't use **server** side code

Comment: @user3088260: fair 'nuf, use a Range if your HTTP server (not php) supports Ranges, as all http1.1 servers should. then you just need a source map of your big file a a list of stuff you need.

Comment: @dandavis the idea is that the script shouldn't require configuring the server.

Comment: @user3088260: who said anything about configuring a server? just use a range request and see if it works. if it doesn't, then you are either SOL or need to adjust apache (if you can), but Range is common

Comment: @dandavis I'm as blank as papyrus right now.. I only have the faintest of ideas about range requests. how are they used?

Comment: cleanup your comment replies and search for "ajax range", it's just one more step on a normal ajax call...